# ByRef Argument Type Mismatch Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I am using windows 7, Excel 2010, VBA. I am getting an error 
"ByRef Argument Type Mismatch". I am assuming it is a problem with my variable type. I found lots of questions like mine but I can't find anything that has helped me figure out my problem.

Variable Declarations

```
'Force explicit variable declaration
Option Explicit
Private dptData(8) As String
Private TSdata(8) As String
Private fiscalYear(8) As String
```

Calling Function

```
parseUserData fiscalYear, dptData, TSdata
```

Called function Prototype

```
Function parseUserData(fiscalYear As String, dptDataAs String, TSdata As String)
```

Comment: You defined string arrays. So, you need to add `ByRef` statement within function input parameters.

Comment: I had that but i took it out. It didn't work with byref in either.

Comment: Please, read this: [Excel: ByRef and ByVal](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/byref-byval.html)

Comment: string array and just string are different.  x(8) as string could be ("1","2",....."8") but x as string is just "1".

Comment: @MaciejLos that's a good and important read but not the reason of error here. Its string  array being passed as argument instead of string.

Comment: OK, I added parenthesis to the function and it worked. Thanks guys.

Comment: @cyboashu, i'm not sure we're talking about the reason of error. Seems, OP doesn't understand what he's doing.

Comment: I understand the difference between passing by reference and value. I had issues with passing a array when i put the size in. But I made the array dynamic so it works now.

Comment: @MaciejLos : Give it some time, there will be new question or a fantastic edit to this one . We all learn  that way. At least I did. :) Right now, he just wants his code to work. Learning can wait. :)

Comment: @cyboashu Ok so if sending a string array I need to add parenthesis to say it is a array. Why does my get key function works which passes a string array and receives a string.

To give an example
Function Called
Function getKeys(ByRef keys As String) Is passed a string array but still works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing an *array* to a `String`. Change the function's signature to accept a `Variant` instead.

```
Public Function parseUserData(fiscalYear As Variant, dptDataAs Variant, TSdata As Variant)
    Debug.Assert IsArray(fiscalYear) And IsArray(dptDataAs) And IsArray(TSdata)
```

A `String` parameter can only ever accept a `String` argument<sup>1</sup>. `Variant` on the other hand, can accept anything - including an array - but then you'll want to `Assert` that you're dealing with an array, so that you halt execution (and prevent a bug) if that's not the case.

#### Why use a Variant over a typed array?

Using a typed array would work, but a typed array can't be coerced from a `Variant` parameter - which means this:

```
Public Sub DoSomething(ByRef args() As String)
```

...can't be invoked with this otherwise perfectly valid array of strings:

```
DoSomething Array("string1", "string2", "string3") ' can't pass a variant array!
```

Changing the signature to `DoSomething(ByRef args As Variant)` makes it work. All you need to do is to use a meaningful, descriptive, pluralized name to your variant array parameters, so that when *IntelliSense* is shown when you invoke that procedure, the name tells you everything you need to know.

#### But... 'Variant' is evil!

No different than many other languages, *type safety* in VBA is essentially *smokes and mirrors*. `Variant` is a very powerful tool and *does* have its uses - *avoid it when you can* doesn't mean *unlearn its existence*. Using it to pass array references around between procedures doesn't hurt the code's readability, maintainability, or stability. `Variant` enables *duck typing* and *late-binding*, and is a legitimate COM type.

It's *a hammer*. Just make sure not everything becomes a nail, and you'll do great.

<sub><sup>1</sup>VBA will implicitly convert other value types to a `String`, but an array can't be coerced into a string, implicitly or explicitly.</sub>

Comment: Why? Note: i'm not a questioner. I do not see the reason to change the type of variable and pass them as a variant.

Comment: @MaciejLos Clearer now?

Comment: No. OP can pass proper data type. He don;t need to change data types.

Comment: @MaciejLos sure. And then come back here with another question when their code breaks down because they're passing typed arrays around without wrapping them in a `Variant`. Typed arrays in VBA are an utter mess. Use `Variant` and save yourself the headaches. I'll wear this downvote as a badge of honor.

Comment: It's not the matter of honor. Upvoted (i hope you'll hapier now). It's the matter  of reason to change data types.

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon LOLOL, also isn't it better practice to use the data type so if someone passes the wrong type to my function then it won't propagate?

Comment: @User MaciejLos *is* correct, you don't *need* to change the data type *in this situation*. But IME passing typed arrays around is a sure-shot way to end up pulling your hair over trying to keep your arrays correctly typed. The `Variant` parameter will accept `Array("string1", "string2", "string3")` - try that with a `args() As String` parameter.

Comment: Thank you, @MathieuGuindon. Let's shake hands in agreement :thumbsup:

Comment: @MaciejLos sorry if I'm coming off as irritated.. having a bad day - I admire your work BTW ...I really need to start writing my own VBA book =)

Comment: Be sure to remove or comment out the Debug.Print and Debug.Assert statements when you are finished debugging. You generally don't want these statements to be operative during normal usage of your application. :)

Comment: Good idea. I'm an author of vba programming book. That's the reason why my comments make people frustrated sometimes ;) Forgive me.

Comment: @DavidZemens unless you have an actual bug, `Debug.Assert` statements wouldn't have any effect - if these assert calls were to fail, then you can definitely expect the rest of the procedure to throw an error anyway. I'd leave them in - what you *do* remove, is `Stop` statements, which unconditionally halt execution. `Debug.Assert` calls are innocuous if you've actually tested your code ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you wanted a string array after all but it may be worth mentioning that you can declare a fixed width string var.

```
Dim dptData As String * 8

dptData = "abc"
Debug.Print Len(dptData) & "|" & dptData & "|"
'result from Immediate window
'8|abc     |

dptData = "abcdefghijk"
Debug.Print Len(dptData) & "|" & dptData & "|"
'result from Immediate window
'8|abcdefgh|
```

Comment: Do you mean concatenate my string array?

Comment: No, I meant if you actually wanted a single string var truncated to 8 characters then this would be the method. I'm not saying it is appropriate in your case now that it has been clarified that you want to work with string arrays (that part was missing from your original question). I'm saying if someone in the future comes across this question looking for a way to create a string var that is only ever 8 characters long, this is how it's done.